# Creating a shared library with a global variable

Tags: c++, dll, g++, shared-libraries

This question is asked in a g++ compiler context under Windows.

Let's say I want to create a shared library, MyLibrary.dll.

MyLibrary.h:

```
#ifndef _MYLIBRARY_H
#define _MYLIBRARY_H

#ifdef MYLIBRARY_DLL_EXPORT
#define MYLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class MYLIBRARY_API XYZ{
public:
    double x;
};

MYLIBRARY_API extern XYZ xyz; // Is this correct, I just want to declare, hence "extern"

#endif
```

MyLibrary.cpp:

```
#include "MyLibrary.h"

XYZ xyz; // DEFINITION OF xyz
```

I then compile this into two files,

```
MyLibrary.dll
libMyLibrary.a
```

Now, lets say I want to use variable **xyz** in a program which I only link against the import library (i.e. with -lMyLibrary), and include the header MyLibrary.h of course.

I seem to be getting an undefined reference when I compile.

```
undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2VX6................
```

How do I define a "global" variable in a shared library, i.e. a variable which exists in one copy and can be shared among threads?

**EDIT:**

I turned out the reason was that I had declared my variable **xyz** inside two namespace in MyLibrary.h. When I moved the variable outside namespaces A and B (i.e. into the global namespace) then it worked.

I had this:

MyLibrary.h:

```
#ifndef _MYLIBRARY_H
#define _MYLIBRARY_H

#ifdef MYLIBRARY_DLL_EXPORT
#define MYLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace A{

namespace B{

class MYLIBRARY_API XYZ{
public:
    double x;
};

MYLIBRARY_API extern XYZ xyz; // Is this correct, I just want to declare, hence "extern"

} // B

} // A

#endif
```

MyLibrary.cpp:

```
#include "MyLibrary.h"

A::B::XYZ xyz; // DEFINITION OF xyz
```

I then tried to use xyz outside MyLibrary by referring to it as

```
A::B::xyz
```

**Question:**
Do I refer to **xyz** in the wrong way or must we place global variables in shared libraries in the global namespace?

Comment: Do you really mean "among threads" or rather "among processes"? And did you define `MYLIBRARY_DLL_EXPORT` on compilation (check the DLL symbols)?

Comment: I mean "among threads", I am not interested in inter-process communication (IPC). See my Edit, I figured out a solution/workaround. I did define MYLIBRARY_DLL_EXPORT when I compiled the library, so the symbol is marked for export.